# No module named kubernetes.dynamic.resource

Tags: python, kubernetes, ansible

I try to deploy some .yaml file with code of Kubernetes, but get error

```
TASK [/cur/develop/inno/777/name.k8s/roles/deploy_k8s_dashboard : Apply the Kubernetes dashboard] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Monday 17 October 2022  13:52:07 +0200 (0:00:00.836)       0:00:01.410 ******** 
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ImportError: No module named kubernetes.dynamic.resource
fatal: [cibd1]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  error: No module named kubernetes.dynamic.resource
  msg: Failed to import the required Python library (kubernetes) on bvm's Python /usr/bin/python. Please read the module documentation and install it in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ImportError: No module named kubernetes.dynamic.resource
fatal: [cibd1]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  error: No module named kubernetes.dynamic.resource
  msg: Failed to import the required Python library (kubernetes) on bvm's Python /usr/bin/python. Please read the module documentation and install it in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter
```

Could you please help with advice, How can I fix it?

Comment: The important error is `Failed to import the required Python library (kubernetes) on bvm's Python /usr/bin/python`. It looks like you're trying to apply Kubernetes resources using Ansible, which means you need to install the `kubernetes` Python module on whichever host you're executing these tasks.

Comment: Try `pip install kubernetes` on your host device as well

Comment: @larsks I use the environment variable "conda", used the package to install Python version 2.7 the error did not appear, but another `The error was: SyntaxError: invalid syntax` appeared. I also installed the package `conda install -c "conda-forge/label/cf202003" python-kubernetes`, but that didn't help either.

Comment: It's possible there is no python 2.7 version. That `SyntaxError` exception is common when trying to run Python 3.x codes on Python 2.7. Python 2.x went end-of-life back in 2020, so support for it is spotty.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem. locally I had to execute the following

```
ansible-galaxy collection install kubernetes.core
```

On the target server make sure that you have python3 installed as python2 won't be enough. Once that is installed, I also had to define the below in my vars:

```
ansible_python_interpreter: /bin/python3
```